# Sacar datos de una tabla de una web

Tags: python, web

Mi pregunta es como sacar los datos de la última cotización de la web de la Bolsa de Madrid. He logrado sacar por pantalla los nombres de las empresas pero no se como sacar tambien sus valores de la última sesión. Gracias.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.bolsamadrid.es/esp/aspx/Mercados/Precios.aspx?indice=ESI100000000&punto=indice'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

# Extraer todas los nombre del archivo HTML
empresas = soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'DifFlSb'})
for empresa in empresas:
    empresastxt = empresa.get_text()
    print(empresastxt)
```

Comment: ¿En qué topas? El "no puedo" es demasiado genérico. ¿Hasta donde has llegado?

Comment: Buenas, he llegado a sacar por pantalla los nombre de las empresas pero no se como sacar el valor de la ultima sesión.

Comment: lo que pasa es que estas obteniendo una columna de toda la fila

Answer (score 2):

Para acceder al elemento que está despues del actual puedes usar el método `next_sibling`

```py
empresas = soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'DifFlSb'})
for empresa in empresas:
    empresastxt = empresa.get_text()
    print(empresa.next_sibling)
```

Otra cosa que recomendaría sería traer toda la fila y luego ir separando los valores, esto lo puedes hacer de varias formas, pero te mostraré una relativamente sencilla. Aprovechando que nos situamos en el primer elemento, podemos usar `next_siblings` que nos dará un iterador de todos los elementos "hermanos" de nuestro elemento actual, es decir las demás columna.

```py
empresas = soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'DifFlSb'})
for empresa in empresas:
    empresastxt = empresa.get_text()
    for col in empresa.next_siblings:
        if col.name:
            print(col.get_text())
```

Con esto ya tenemos todos los datos de la fila, lo único que faltaría sería ordenarlos bien, por ejemplo dentro de una lista